# Need help to 'async' a Function("...").call() for firestore

Tags: typescript, async-await

Good day gurus,

i structured my code to allow dynamic input string (sCmd) from user, then the string will be push into function like

```
let res = Function("moment", '"use strict";' + sCmd).call(this, moment);
```

here is a sample of user input, which allowed them to call an 'await' command

```
let sCmd = `
    // ---- cmd START
    function simulateFirebaseGet() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('resolved from simulateFirebaseGet()');
        }, 2000);
      });
    }
    async function callAsyncFunc() {
      console.log('#2 - run callAsyncFunc()');

      let res = await simulateFirebaseGet();
      console.log('#3 - start wait 2 sec')
      console.log('#4 -', res);
      console.log('#5 - waited 2 sec')
    }

    console.log('#1 - START Function()');
     callAsyncFunc()
    console.log('#6 - STOP Function()');
    // ---- cmd END
    `;
```

But it doesn't work as per my expectation. Console log

```
#1 - START Function()
#2 - run callAsyncFunc()
#6 - STOP Function()
#3 - start wait 2 sec
#4 - resolved from simulateFirebaseGet()
#5 - waited 2 sec
```

I am expecting something below

```
#1 - START Function()
#2 - run callAsyncFunc()
#3 - start wait 2 sec
#4 - resolved from simulateFirebaseGet()
#5 - waited 2 sec
#6 - STOP Function()
```

I have also provide a [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2qu5st?). If i put 'await' to

```
await callAsyncFunc()
```

i will get error `Error: Unexpected identifier`

updates:
After @CertainPerformance replied, i picked up the second approach and it run in sequence. cool! But soon i noticed once i change the caller to

```
console.log("START OUTSIDE Function()");
let res = Function("moment", '"use strict";' + sCmd).call(
  this,
  moment
); 
console.log("STOP OUTSIDE Function()");
```

The console log output as

```
START OUTSIDE Function()
#1 - START Function()
run helper
#2 - run callAsyncFunc()
STOP OUTSIDE Function()
#3 - start wait 2 sec
#4 - resolved from simulateFirebaseGet()
#5 - waited 2 sec
#6 - STOP Function()
```

And i would need it to run as

```
START OUTSIDE Function()
#1 - START Function()
run helper
#2 - run callAsyncFunc()
#3 - start wait 2 sec
#4 - resolved from simulateFirebaseGet()
#5 - waited 2 sec
#6 - STOP Function()
STOP OUTSIDE Function()
```

In my use case, i would have to loop "Function(...).call()" and they need to be process in sequence. Results in earlier loop will be use for calculation in the later item in the "Function(...).call()".

Answer (score 0):

Either put the `#6` inside a `.then` after `callAsyncFn()` resolves, or put the whole function into an IIFE so you can `await` the call of `callAsyncFn`:

```js
let sCmd = `
    // ---- cmd START
    function simulateFirebaseGet() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('resolved from simulateFirebaseGet()');
        }, 2000);
      });
    }
    async function callAsyncFunc() {
      console.log('#2 - run callAsyncFunc()');

      let res = await simulateFirebaseGet();
      console.log('#3 - start wait 2 sec')
      console.log('#4 -', res);
      console.log('#5 - waited 2 sec')
    }

    console.log('#1 - START Function()');
     callAsyncFunc().then(() => {
        console.log('#6 - STOP Function()');
        // ---- cmd END
    });
    `;
    let res = Function("moment", '"use strict";' + sCmd).call(this, {});
```

or

```js
let sCmd = `
    // ---- cmd START
    (async () => {

      function simulateFirebaseGet() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('resolved from simulateFirebaseGet()');
          }, 2000);
        });
      }
      async function callAsyncFunc() {
        console.log('#2 - run callAsyncFunc()');

        let res = await simulateFirebaseGet();
        console.log('#3 - start wait 2 sec')
        console.log('#4 -', res);
        console.log('#5 - waited 2 sec')
      }

      console.log('#1 - START Function()');
      await callAsyncFunc()
      console.log('#6 - STOP Function()');
      // ---- cmd END
  })();
    `;
    let res = Function("moment", '"use strict";' + sCmd).call(this, {});
```

You'll need to do the same sort of thing outside - either `await` the call of the constructed function, or call `.then` on it.

```js
let sCmd = `
    // ---- cmd START
    function simulateFirebaseGet() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('resolved from simulateFirebaseGet()');
        }, 2000);
      });
    }
    async function callAsyncFunc() {
      console.log('#2 - run callAsyncFunc()');

      let res = await simulateFirebaseGet();
      console.log('#3 - start wait 2 sec')
      console.log('#4 -', res);
      console.log('#5 - waited 2 sec')
    }

    console.log('#1 - START Function()');
    return callAsyncFunc().then(() => {
        console.log('#6 - STOP Function()');
        // ---- cmd END
    });
    `;
console.log("START OUTSIDE Function()");
Function("moment", '"use strict";' + sCmd).call(
  this,
  {}
)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("STOP OUTSIDE Function()");
  });
```

Comment: your second method worked! but my in my use case, i have to loop "Function().call", it doesn't 'wait' outside 'Function().call'. i will update my logic in my thread to elaborate more detail.

Comment: See edit, you need to do the same thing you did inside, outside too, so that the Promises get chained together properly

Comment: your code work. But for my use case, i need to run through Function(...).call in a loop form. meaning i couldn't control the number Function(...).call for every instance. Your chain method will not suit for my use case :(